# OpenCV Mat processing Android JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, matrix

I am currently developing some stuff using OpenCv's Android API and the JNI for faster processing.

Currently, the program gets a frame from the device-camera and just forwards the RGBA-Matrix to the JNI-interfaced C++ algorithm.

This generally works, but when trying to process the matrix in any way, I get a SIGABRT -6 error with following trace:

```
D/JNI/LaneDetection(15547): Processing frame
D/JNI/LaneDetection(15547): frame type: 24
D/JNI/LaneDetection(15547): frame rows, cols: 1080, 1920
D/JNI/LaneDetection(15547): grey_frame type: 24
D/JNI/LaneDetection(15547): grey_frame rows, cols: 1080, 1920
I/DEBUG   (  242):     #00 pc 00036d58  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
I/DEBUG   (  242):     #01 pc 00014231  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
I/DEBUG   (  242):     #02 pc 00014f93  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
I/DEBUG   (  242):     #03 pc 000116a5  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
I/DEBUG   (  242):     #04 pc 0000fd3c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
I/DEBUG   (  242):     #05 pc 00724ce4  /data/app/at.sapps.sdo-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java.so (__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()+276)
I/DEBUG   (  242):     #06 pc 007220e8  /data/app/at.sapps.sdo-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java.so (__cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)())+8)
I/DEBUG   (  242):     #07 pc 0072212c  /data/app/at.sapps.sdo-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java.so (std::terminate()+20)
I/DEBUG   (  242):     #08 pc 007222b4  /data/app/at.sapps.sdo-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java.so (__cxa_throw+148)
I/DEBUG   (  242):     #09 pc 001a5a41  /data/app/at.sapps.sdo-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java.so (cv::error(cv::Exception const&)+80)
I/DEBUG   (  242):     #10 pc 00267243  /data/app/at.sapps.sdo-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java.so (cv::cvarrToMat(void const*, bool, bool, int)+134)
I/DEBUG   (  242):     #11 pc 0035bcbb  /data/app/at.sapps.sdo-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java.so (cvCvtColor+22)
I/DEBUG   (  242):     #12 pc 00006195  /data/app/at.sapps.sdo-2/lib/arm/liblane_tracker_module.so (onFrame(cv::Mat*)+252)
```

the corresponding C++ call which causes the error is the following:

```
cvCvtColor(frame, grey, CV_RGBA2GRAY); // convert to grayscale
```

As you might have noticed, matrix types and dimensions are the same. I've also tried CV_BGRA2GRAY with the same result. (However, I am pretty sure it's an RGBA matrix, since the javaapi call is inputframe.rgba() to get the matrix..)

the Mat grey gets initialized with the following calls:

```
    Mat *grey = new Mat(frame_size, 24); // global, 24=type= same as original frame Mat
    // method init:
    video_size.height = frame->rows;
    video_size.width = frame->cols;
    frame_size = cvSize(video_size.width, video_size.height);
    grey = new cv::Mat(frame_size, 24, 3);
```

I can't figure out what the actual problem is, maybe due to my lack of c++ skills.

I appreciate every help & thank you in advance.

java code in a nutshell:

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
 rgbaMat = inputFrame.rgba();
 nativeDetect(rgbaMat.getNativeObjAddr(), lanes.getNativeObjAddr());
 return rgbaMat;
}


private static native void nativeDetect(long inputImage, long lanes);
```

ANSWER: The used C methods were the root of all evil. Changing them to their C++ equivalents resolved this issue

Comment: I added the java code. 
current constructor is Mat* grey = new Mat(frame_size, 24);  which doesn't work either (i am open for suggestions). 
Type "24" is originating from the original frame-Mat, the camera API hands over. That's why I took the same, as I read there are compability issues if you take different types of matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but this C++ code, is confusing for me. What type is 24 or 3 in the constructor... I think, you should use OpenCV constants to define types. Also, you are using the C function instead of using the C++ function

Anyway, the method `cv::cvtColor` should allocate the necessary memory, and you only need to do:

```
Mat grey;
cv::cvtColor(frame, grey, CV_RGBA2GRAY);
```

Finally,  I would clone your input frame (`frame`) to avoid memory problems with your Android code:

```
cv::Mat newMat = frame.clone()
```

Search in the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/) to find C++ functions..

Comment: I've edited stuff + added a comment to the question.

Comment: the above code didn't work. What's the exact reason for frame.clone() ? How would duplicating a frame solve memory problems? Do you mean regarding to concurrency?

Comment: The Android SDK for OpenCV allocates each frame in the range of memory and it could overwrite the frame which you are processing...  How do you create the Mat frame? Also which error throws with my answer?

Comment: Ah well thanks.
"frame" is the result auf the OpenCV-Android Camera API as seen in the Java source code. I mainly just cast the native adress jlong to the Mat*, as it's been done in several examples:

cv::Mat* frame = (cv::Mat*) inputImage;

Comment: Also, you are using cvCvtColor, what it is C function, you should use cv::cvtColor with is the [C++ function] (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html). It is possible that C funcion doesn't allocate memory

Comment: Wow, apparently that did the job.

Now I need to find the equivalences for the other C-methods I am using to come to the same result.  (cvSmooth, cvCanny, cvHoughLines2).
Could you edit the "C method thing" into your answer? Then I'll accept it.

+ is there any other way to manually allocate the memory needed for the Mat such that I could keep using the C functions ? (just theoretically)

Comment: All these methods has  a C++ version... It helps a lot and it you will be able to forget all these details (types, allocating...). You can find all necessary C++ functions in the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/) but if you prefers a [pdf](http://docs.opencv.org/opencv_cheatsheet.pdf)  (for 2.4)

Comment: Well thank you, please edit into your answer that C methods were the issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any constructor such as you used while define "grey". Can you change that with below.

```
 grey = new cv::Mat(frame_size, CV_8UC1);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: the constructor used was: 
 grey = new cv::Mat(frame_size, 24, 3);

as "24" was the frame-rgba-matrix type as you see in the trace

I'll try your solution too though.

edit: same error, however type of "grey" is now 0 (while the original frame is type 24)

Comment: I suppose gray image should be 1 channel and if you just define your destination image like "Mat grey;" , cvtColor function should handle initialization parameters of matrix as mentioned in the [book.](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=UjWoIFHcr58C&pg=PT105&lpg=PT105&dq=CV_BGRA2GRAY&source=bl&ots=S9e4Brrt-x&sig=XZZzW8pDBFrn5H3KOo1wT66RqKk&hl=tr&sa=X&ei=e3f0VOC9FcmWarWMgNAK&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=CV_BGRA2GRAY&f=false)

Comment: you mean like: "Mat* grey = new Mat();" ? Or just "Mat* grey;" the "destination-image" of the color conversion IS the matrix "grey"

Comment: I mean just "Mat* grey"

Comment: trying... give me a second.